# Delete S3 object with slashes in object name using REST API

Tags: php, rest, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm having trouble deleting an object in one of my buckets which uses slashes in the object name to help with organization.

For example, my bucket name is `wecombinate` and my object name is `products/images/image1.png`

When I try to delete, I get "[BucketNotEmpty] The bucket you tried to delete is not empty" as if I'm trying to delete the whole bucket, which I'm not, I am using the DELETE object REST API request to delete the single item `products/images/image1.png`.

I'm using the popular https://github.com/tpyo/amazon-s3-php-class PHP class to manage S3 and the code seems fine, plus no issues reported on GitHub.

The code to do the delete:

```
$s3->deleteObject('wecombinate', 'products/images/image1.png');
```

Is there a known problem with using slashes in the object name?  Any other things I might be missing?

Comment: Try this. S3::deleteObject('wecombinate','products/images/image1.png');

Comment: @IqbalMalik yes, that's exactly how I am doing it...

Comment: This link might have info you need.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/DeletingOneObjectUsingPHPSDK.html

Comment: @IqbalMalik Thanks for the link. I have read the Amazon docs and have found nothing related to my problem unfortunately.

Comment: Try it with a leading slash: `$s3->deleteObject('wecombinate', '/products/images/image1.png')` and see if that changes anything.

Comment: @dcro That did it, thanks! It seems I'd tried everything but that.  If you add your comment as the answer I'll accept it

Comment: No problem, glad it works! I posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a leading slash to the key to get it working:

```
$s3->deleteObject('wecombinate', '/products/images/image1.png')
```